# RSpec Controller Testing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am very new to RSpec. I am trying to do a basic controller test for Rails app. I want to check that when I use the PostsController's "create" action, the user gets redirected to the posts path. Here is my current test.

```
 describe "POST #create" do 
  it "returns http success" do
   post :create, {'post' => { :title => "My first post", :author => 'Jack Seabolt'} }
   expect(response). to have_http_status(:success) 
  end

  it "redirects to 'index' template" do 
   post :create , {'post' => {:title => "my first post", :author => 'Jack Seabolt'} }
   expect(response) redirect_to(posts_path)
  end 
end
```

This code leads to this error:

```
/Users/johnseabolt/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1435:in `load':    
/Users/johnseabolt/Desktop/projects/tdd/spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb:49: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
  expect(response) redirect_to(posts_path)
                              ^
```

I've attempting adding just 'posts'. I tried 'index'. Didn't work. If someone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Any luck with finding a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You've missed to call a method `to` for `expect`:

```
expect(response).to redirect_to(posts_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually the formula for an expectation is something like:

```
expect( something ).to eq another_thing
expect( something ).to be another_thing
```

or

```
expect( something ).to_not eq another_thing
expect( something ).to_not be another_thing
```

In your case, you don't need the `be` or `eq` cause of the `redirect_to` matcher.

```
expect(response).to redirect_to(posts_path)
```

**DOCS:**

docs for `redirect_to` matcher: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-5/docs/matchers/redirect-to-matcher

docs for `be` matchers: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/be-matchers

docs for `eq` matchers: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/equality-matchers